# FQL with limit do not return results for all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Im tryint to get the following query to return results for two of my friends:

```
SELECT pid, owner
FROM photo
WHERE aid IN (
  SELECT aid
   FROM album
   WHERE owner in (
     SELECT uid2
     FROM friend
     WHERE uid1=me()
     LIMIT 0, 2 ) )
```

But for some reason it does only show result for one of them, and the number of rows returned is not above the limit (only about 800)

When I run:

```
SELECT uid2
FROM friend
WHERE uid1=me()
LIMIT 0, 2
```

I get a result with two friends, as expected and when I manually do a query in this form:

```
SELECT pid, owner
FROM photo
WHERE aid IN (
  SELECT aid
   FROM album
   WHERE owner = USER_ID_FROM_LAST_QUERY
```

I get the result Id expect for both users, but Why wont it work with the IN-statement and subquery?

Edit: What I try to achieve is to get the photos of all my friends. And just asking for all photos from ALL my friends would be more then 5000 photos, and thus I cant get everything in 1 query.

Currently I got it working by doing a query for each user, to get all his pictures - and it works fine. (if you ignore the fact that it takes 2-3 minutes to execute. So I want to shorten the runtime by doing fewer queries.

Edit: more info:

With the following query i get albums from both users:

```
SELECT aid, owner
FROM album
WHERE owner in (
  SELECT uid2
  FROM friend
  WHERE uid1=me()
  LIMIT 0, 2 )
```

But with the full query, i only get pictures from albums owned by one of those users.

Comment: I would suggest you to use two queries one for each friend. What I think is it gets all photos from first friends and exhausting the limit and does not get the photos of second friend.

Comment: Then I would have to do a new query for each friend (I actually want from all my friends). And the run time with that aproach is about 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

SELECT pid, owner FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() LIMIT 2 ) )

Comment: Will not this return only two pid, what he has trying limit it friends (2) and not photos.

Comment: As the one above me states, I want all photos from 2 of my friends - not just 2 photos from my friends. I actually want all the photos of all my friends; but this is to much data to get in 1 query.

Comment: Problem is here SELECT pid, owner FROM photo WHERE aid IN (xxxx,yyyy) This Query returns only records for yyyy aid not for both. I am still searching why

Comment: That seems to be the issue. I wonder if this is a bug or just something not documented.